# Is the structure "X, whom I've had the pleasure of being the mentor of" proper?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, whom, pied-piping

John is the mentor of Anna. John introduces Anna as:

1. "Anna, whom I've had the pleasure of being the mentor **of**".

Would the following be more correct?

2. "Anna, **of** whom I've had the pleasure of being the mentor"

Comment: I've changed all X to Anna, and Y to John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is only "more correct" if you don't like ending phrases like that with prepositions. Many people might think it sounds weirdly formal.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified the context. This is a recommendation letter, so this is supposed to be relatively formal. Thanks!

Comment: @UğurY.Yavuz Some people might say it's more correct, but the second way is definitely not wrong. You could also reword the sentence to avoid this ("X, who(m) I've had the pleasure of mentoring...", "I have had the pleasure of being the mentor of X, who...").

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice. That way of wording seems more natural.

Answer (score 3):

The second way is closer to being correct, but a bit awkwardly phrased. You might instead say

> This is Anna, whom I've had the pleasure of mentoring

or in a more relevant example

> Anna, whom I've had the pleasure of mentoring, has shown great dedication to her subject material

Comment: That definitely seems more convenient and natural. Thanks.